# Where did dev console datastore query go?

Tags: google-app-engine

Previously I could write a query to examine the contents of my datastore, but in the new Developers Console all I see is the "Filters" button. It's great that now I don't have to write an actual query for a basic select, but that also means I can't do anything other than the equivalent of SELECT *.

I usually need to specify WHERE or order the results to find what I need, and that is not possible with the Filters button. Where did the query form go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "filters" button at `https://console.developers.google.com/project/<projname>/datastore/query` are exactly the `WHERE` you're looking for.  Pick the property, type, and comparison, from the dropboxes, and enter the value to compare against, then click `Apply`.

For "order by", click on the column header of the result, on which you want to sort (typical "sortable web table" behavior).

Comment: Ah, now I see a mouseover will show a tiny gray arrow for some of the column headers. This is not particularly visible on my display and is smaller than my default font size. Thanks, that is helpful to know. The UI is fairly good about respecting font sizes for text, but not everything is text. 

The WHERE situation is still a bit tedious, adding tons of clauses and trying to keep them all straight. I also can't do much of the text searching I'm accustomed to with standard SQL (but that isn't a UI issue.)

Comment: @feorlen, right, that's a datastore/NoSQL issue -- querying is very different (I remember how painful is what to learn non-relational querying 10 years ago after 20 years of SQL...!).  But the inability to copy and past queries IS a loss of functionality: I used to keep a text file with queries ready to C&P and can't any more.  I also miss the ability to similarly C&P snippets of Python code...